# Unable to to get the cell clicked from a Datatable (jquery)

Tags: jquery, jsp, datatable, cell

I'm using the last version of jquery datatables (1.10.12) but I'm not be able to get what cell is clicked. Following the documentation example, I always receive an "undefined". Maybe the problem is with datatable definition? I can see all the clciekd row info (first console.log) but not the cell!

```
    $('#table_id tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
        console.log( table.row( this ).data());
        console.log(table.cell( this ).index());
        console.log(table.cell( this ).data());
    });
```

Best wishes,

Ivan

https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell().data()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are passing `tr` to the cell() method.

```
$('#table_id tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () { // its a click on tr
        console.log(table.cell( this ).data()); // this <- is tr , will not work!
    });
```

do this

```
$('#table_id tbody').on( 'click', 'td', function () { // its a click on td
        console.log(table.cell( this ).data()); // this <- is td
    });
```